# Facebook Graph API to get user photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to ask about how to get users' photos from a photo album using Facebook graph API. I am trying some other coding by which I can get users' profile name and his/her profile picture, but I want to get photos. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you

This is the what I am using for getting user profile picture and user name:

```
if ($user)
    {
      try
      {
        $f=$facebook->api('/me');
         $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e)
       {
         echo $e;
         $user = null;
       }
    }
echo $f['name']."<br/><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$f['id']."/picture' width='50' height='50' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried /{user-id}/albuns?